# Issue with Socket AF_INET & SOCK_STREAM

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

I want to run a [Android Screenshot Library's JNI code](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) in my android application.

According to its [docs](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/wiki/Usage), you just have to run a .bat/.sh file which copies the native code into device, executes it & start the service. Which works.

But I'm creating an app which copies this native code from its assets folder to device and then starts the service.

I'm able to copy the file and executes the code, but the service is not getting started.

Upon closer look I've found the issue in **[main.c](https://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/source/browse/#hg%2Fnative)**'s following line of code:

```
Log("Starting server...");
int sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sfd < 0)    return -1;
Log("- Socket creation");
```

Issue is with `sdf` & log *- Socket creation* never gets printed.

I'm not too familiar with **JNI & C**, that's why I'm seeking expert comments.

Here is log file, when .bat file is successfully executed:

```
Program initialized
Starting server...
- Socket creation
- Socket binding
- Socket in listening mode
Server started.
Listening on 0.0.0.0:42380
Signal handling setup
Starting main loop.
<< select() on sockets... >>
```

And here is the log file from my application:

```
Program initialized
Starting server...
Error while starting server
Signal handling setup
Starting main loop.
<< select() on sockets... >>
```

I've also added, in manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Please suggest.

Comment: on linux you have to execute code with "sudo" to bind socket to port in admin group which is less than 1024